# give a 'rank value' to large rasters

Tags: matlab, probability, raster, rank

I have rasters with probabilities (pforest,ppasture) and I will give a rank to the values within the raster so that the highest probability receives value 1, the 2nd highest value 2, ....

I tried this but it failed.It gives an output but not the right output. Anyone a real solution?

```
RankforestH=zeros(592,1339);
  [ignore,idx]=sort(pforest);
rank(idx)=1:numel(idx);
RankforestH(:)=rank;

 RankpastureH=zeros(592,1339);
  [ignore,idx]=sort(ppasture);
rank(idx)=1:numel(idx3);
RankpastureH(:)=rank;
;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and explain why the output you are currently receiving is not the output you desire.

Comment: I assume the size of `pforest` and `ppasture` is `[592,1339]`, is that correct?

Comment: By the way, opening duplicate questions is generally frowned upon. It would be better to improve your original question by adding your code and examples.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RankforestH = zeros(size(pforest));
[~,idx] = sort(pforest, 'descend');
RankforestH(idx) = 1:numel(idx);
```